# Resolving performance issue with skewed partitions in PySpark Window function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting to calculate some moving averages in Spark, but am running into issues with skewed partitions. Here is the simple calculation I'm trying to perform:

### Getting the base data

```py
# Variables
one_min = 60
one_hour = 60*one_min
one_day = 24*one_hour
seven_days = 7*one_day
thirty_days = 30*one_day

# Column variables
target_col = "target"
partition_col = "partition_col"


df_base = (
    spark
    .sql("SELECT * FROM {base}".format(base=base_table))
)

df_product1 = (
    df_base
    .where(F.col("product_id") == F.lit("1"))
    .select(
        F.col(target_col).astype("double").alias(target_col),
        F.unix_timestamp("txn_timestamp").alias("window_time"),
        "transaction_id",
        partition_col
    )
)
df_product1.persist()
```

### Calculating running averages

```py
window_lengths = {
    "1day": one_day,
    "7day": seven_days,
    "30day": thirty_days
}
# Create window specs for each type
part_windows = {
    time: Window.partitionBy(F.col(partition_col))
                .orderBy(F.col("window_time").asc())
                .rangeBetween(-secs, -one_min)
    for (time, secs) in window_lengths.items()
}

cols = [
    # Note: not using `avg` as I will be smoothing this at some point
    (F.sum(target_col).over(win)/F.count("*").over(win)).alias(
        "{time}_avg_target".format(time=time)
    )
    for time, win in part_windows.items()
]

sample_df = (
    df_product1
    .repartition(2000, partition_col)
    .sortWithinPartitions(F.col("window_time").asc())
    .select(
        "*",
        *cols
    )
)
```

Now, I can `collect` a limited subset of these data (say just 100 rows), but if I try to run the full query, and, for example, aggregate the running averages, Spark gets stuck on some particularly large partitions. The *vast* majority of the partitions have fewer than 1million records in them. Only about 50 of them have more than 1M record and only about 150 have more than 500K

However, a small handful have more than 2.5M (~10), and 3 of them have more than 5M records. These partitions have run for more than 12 hours and failed to complete. The skew in these partitions are a natural part of the data representing larger activity in these distinct values of the partitioning column. I have no control over the definition of the values of this partitioning column.

I am using a `SparkSession` with dynamic allocation enabled, 32G of RAM and 4 cores per executor, and 4 executors minimum. I have attempted to up the executors to 96G with 8 cores per executor and 10 executors minimum, but the job still does not complete.

This seems like a calculation which shouldn't take 13 hours to complete. The `df_product1` DataFrame contains just shy of 300M records.

If there is other information that would be helpful in resolving this problem, please comment below.

Comment: How was this completed?